# Pattern for "load local, then update, then remote and maybe update"

Tags: caching, design-patterns, callback, promise, future

I'm looking for a coding pattern that comfortably solves the following problem: This is a paradigm I find myself having to use a lot in my development. After the user opens any UI likely the following is happening:

1. Load data from local storage
2. Update UI with local data
3. Load data from remote
4. Store remote data to local storage
5. Update UI with remote data

A simple example would be loading a Twitter timeline for example. The app will present to the user what it has, updates from remote in the background and then updates the UI if it found more recent tweets.

Ideally, each step would run async and be cancelable at any time. I've been using a mix of **Futures**/**Promises** and **Callbacks** so far but I find myself writing a lot of glue code...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have working code and you'd like suggestions for how to make it a lot cleaner, then this may be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  As your question stands now, it seems a bit too general/generic to draw an actual code solution because you haven't included any of your own code.  It certainly seems you could write a single function that would manage all five of those steps and be reusable.  But, the specifics of how to do that are not particularly generic as they depend on your specific needs.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought... I actually didn't kniw about codereview.se Thanks for telling me

Comment: If you want to represent data that is updated multiple times you may want to have a look at FRP, not promises. Promises can only settle once.

Comment: @Bergi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming ?

Comment: @der_michael: Yes, that one.